# trying to create a div element at the top of the body element

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a div element with id "blackout" at the start of the body element, but my code doesn't do what I expect and doesn't create anything.

Am I using prepend wrong? Or do I have to use document.createElement?

Code:

```
function InitModal() {
    $("body").prepend("<div id=\"blackout\"></div>");
}
```

Comment: Your use of quotes in the second example is incorrect. Any errors in your console? How do you call `InitModal`?

Comment: You need to call the function "InitModal()" from somewhere, just use this $(document).ready(function() instead

Comment: please stick to the issue: the code doesn't create anything. of course I call the function come on

Comment: Try in the console of the dev tools directly!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function, otherwise it won't run. I added a call on page load. Also, you got your quotes  wrong. If you surround your code with `'` use `"` for the inner code and vice versa.

```js
function InitModal() {
    $('body').prepend('<div id="blackout">New div</div>');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    InitModal();
});
```

```css
#original{
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#blackout{
  background-color: #A6F1CD;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="original">Original div</div>
```

Comment: the function gets called from another function at startup

Comment: the problem is that it doesn't produce anything

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly fine! Open the developer tools wherever you've got  jQuery, paste the function and call `InitModal()`. Then you'll see in the dev tools that the div has been created.

In your case it seems that the code bit does not get called.

Just put e.g. an `alert('called');` to function and you'll see.